# $A.util.removeClass not working for <tr>...</tr>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, js

I am trying to hide or show the table rows by clicking on first row with the below code of Aura component. But neither addClass, removeClass or toggleClass works for me. Am I missing something?

HTML:

```
<aura:attribute name="toggleStatus" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.updatedDataPrice}" var="dataPrice" indexVar="index">
        <tr>
            <th class="" scope="col" colspan="2">
                <div class="slds-text-heading_small expandCollapse"  onclick="{!c.collapseFeature}" data-id="{!dataPrice.Name}">
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.toggleStatus}"> 
                        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:chevrondown" alternativeText="Hide" title="Hide" size="x-small"></lightning:icon>
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:chevronright" alternativeText="Show" title="Show" size="x-small"></lightning:icon>
                    </aura:set>
                    </aura:if>
                    <b>&nbsp;{!dataPrice.Name + ' ( ' + dataPrice.price + ' )'}</b>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset slds-hide" aura:id="{!'tableContent1-' + dataPrice.Name}">
            <...something...>
        </tr>
        <aura:iteration items="{!dataPrice.subData__r}" var="subData" indexVar="index2" >
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset slds-hide" id="{!subData.Id}" name="{!index2}" aura:id="{!'tableContent2-' + subData.Name}" > 
                <...something...>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
let toggleStatus = component.get("v.toggleStatus");
if(toggleStatus){
    component.set("v.toggleStatus",!toggleStatus);
    let elementsWithTableContentClass1 = component.find("tableContent1-"+event.currentTarget.dataset.id);
    $A.util.addClass(elementsWithTableContentClass1, "slds-hide");
    
    let elementsWithTableContentClass2 = component.find("tableContent2-"+event.currentTarget.dataset.id);
    if(Array.isArray(elementsWithTableContentClass2)) {
        elementsWithTableContentClass2.forEach(function(element) {
            $A.util.addClass(element, "slds-hide");
                });
            } else {
                // Handle single element scenario
                $A.util.addClass(elementsWithTableContentClass2, "slds-hide");
    }
}else{
    component.set("v.toggleStatus",!toggleStatus);
    let elementsWithTableContentClass1 = component.find("tableContent2-"+event.currentTarget.dataset.id);
    $A.util.removeClass(elementsWithTableContentClass1, "slds-hide");
    
    let elementsWithTableContentClass2 = component.find("tableContent2-"+event.currentTarget.dataset.id);
    if(Array.isArray(elementsWithTableContentClass2)) {
        elementsWithTableContentClass2.forEach(function(element) {
            $A.util.removeClass(element, "slds-hide");
                });
            } else {
                // Handle single element scenario
                $A.util.removeClass(elementsWithTableContentClass2, "slds-hide");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing CSS changes in the controller with changes to bound attributes in the template may have undesirable results. Remember: changes you make to attributes don't render until the next time the UI gets a chance to update (e.g. when your controller method ends or goes asynchronous). Consider using just one method or the other.

On the other hand, what you're apparently trying to do can be solved with no extra code using [`lightning:treeGrid`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/example). You may want to consider using that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But lightning:treeGrid is not satisfying my requirements.
On the other hand, I found the issue in my code. I was using component.find()  to find the aura:id from vanilla HTML elements instead I should have been using document.getElementById() and document.getElementById().getAttribute().